# How to wait a certain amount of time without freezing code in C#/Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a practice game to get used to coding where you have to shoot a bird. When you run out of bullets, you need to press the 'r' key to reload your bullets. I want there to be a delay between when the button is pressed and when the bullets reload, but so far what I found is code that freezes everything (shown below). Is there a way to keep the code from freezing everything?
Summary: The code below freezes everything (the whole game) when pressing the 'r' button. Is there code I can use that won't freeze everything and will only wait 2 seconds before running the next action?

```
    IEnumerator TimerRoutine()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);   //Fix this, freezes everything
            activeBullets = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Coroutines To set This delay

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && isDelayDone) // defined isDelayDone as private bool = true;
    {
        // When you press the Key
        isDelayDone = false;

        StartCoroutine(Delay());
        IEnumerator Delay()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            isDelayDone = true;
            activeBullets = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are waiting 2 seconds after the key press but not waiting for the actual key event it.

Here is a modified version of your method doing what you want.

```
IEnumerator TimerRoutine()
{
    while(activeBullets == 0) // Use the bullets value to check if its been reloaded
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) // Key event check each frame
        {
            // Key event fired so wait 2 seconds before reloading the bullets and exiting the Coroutine
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2); 
            activeBullets = reloadBulletsAmount;
            break;
        }   
        yield return null; // Use null for the time value so it waits each frame independant of how long it is
    }
}
```

*(I know this has an accepted answer I just feel this method would be better)*